# How to convert from a HTML page containing a text to JSON

Tags: java, json, string

Suppose I input a text via TextArea in an HTML page. How do I convert it into JSON form using Eclipse?
Example of the string which I am entering using the TextArea is

For the AWSDataTransfer product, this is the public pricing plan.
Regarding data transfer across EC2 AZs:
In all AWS regions, inbound is $0.01/GB.
In all AWS regions, outbound is $0.01/GB.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in a bit more detail?  Which application server/framework are you using?  Do you want it just as a single string e.g. `{"text": "For the AWS..."}` or structured based on sub parts of the string?

Comment: What do you mean for saying that: How do Iconvert it into json form using eclipse.??

Comment: I want it into a form Map-List-String. I want to write a java program which would open a file containing the information which I supply via Text Area in an HTML page and convert it into JSON form.

Comment: `{"myString":"For the AWSDataTransfer product, this is the public pricing plan. Regarding data transfer across EC2 AZs: In all AWS regions, inbound is $0.01/GB. In all AWS regions, outbound is $0.01/GB."}`. Without more information, it's hard to tell what you're really looking for.

Comment: I want it converted to a JSON form which would look like

"Product" : "AWSDataTransfer",
    "PlanName" : "public",
    
    "EC2Regional" : [
        {"region" : "all", "type" : "in", "rate" : "$0.01/GB"},
        {"region" : "all", "type" : "out", "rate" : "$0.01/GB"}
    ],

Answer (score 0):

I guess by "Eclipse" you mean "Java in Eclipse editor". A simple solution is to use DOM to examine the HTML elements, then use a JSON lib in Java to construct an object. There is a good lib for JSON in Java. You can google it at ease. After having the Java's JSON object, you can convert it to string if you want, using toString().